# app crashes when a block of code is included in a loop

Tags: android, loops

I have a block of code creating arraylists, adapter and onclickitemlistener and it works great ONLY if it is meant to work once. I want to include the block in a loop so it's performed several times, but when I do so the app crashes when I want to go to that activity so the block does not run even once... what may be the reason?

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    int c=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);

        final ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();


        TextView tvTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTo);
        ListView lvLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLV);

        DataWraper dwF = (DataWraper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
        ArrayList<Word> wordList = dwF.GetWords();
        for(Word w : wordList) {
            words.add(w.GetSth()+"."+w.GetSthElse());
        }

//  do {
        Generator set = new Generator(words);                   
        ArrayList<String> s = set.GetQuizSet();

        final String palabra = s.get(0).substring(s.get(0).indexOf(".")+1);
        tvTo.setText(s.get(0).substring(0, s.get(0).indexOf(".")));

        Collections.shuffle(s);
        final ArrayList<String> sp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String o : s) {
        transl.add(o.substring(o.indexOf(".")+1));
        }
        MAdapter la = new MAdapter(MyClass.this, sp);
        lvLV.setAdapter(la);

        lvLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(sp.get(position).matches(palabra)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
//              c++;
            }
        });
//  } while(c<5);
}
}
```

Comment: Without any code, it's very difficult to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Post your crash log as well !!

Comment: I forgot to add that logcat clearsout quickly, there is nothing about errors, that's why I'm asking here because I can't figure out anything.

Comment: Without any code, I could say that your task is too long that it should be run in background, as an async task.

Comment: Whatever the block of code is, if its not in the onCreate() of your Activity/fragment, that block of code won't execute after your application is killed.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: "I forgot to add that logcat clears out quickly," -- Logcat does not clear out nearly that quickly. You can unlock the scrolling and scroll up to where the exception happened and copy the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting a `StackOverflowError`. You only increment `c` in the `OnItemClickListener`, so it's not getting incremented in `onCreate()`, and your while-loop is running endlessly.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, or what exactly all your classes are, I juggled your code a bit. You might want to structure your code more like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity
{
    int c = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);

        final ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        TextView tvTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTo);
        ListView lvLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLV);

        DataWraper dwF = (DataWraper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");

        ArrayList<Word> wordList = dwF.GetWords();
        for (Word w : wordList)
        {
            words.add(w.GetSth() + "." + w.GetSthElse());
        }

        final ArrayList<String> sp = new ArrayList<String>();

        MAdapter la = new MAdapter(MyClass.this, sp);

        lvLV.setAdapter(la);
        lvLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    //*** Your call to generate() will go in here
                    //*** depending on where you want it

                    if (sp.get(position).matches(palabra))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private void generate()
    {
        if (c < 5)
        {
            Generator set = new Generator(words);                   
            ArrayList<String> s = set.GetQuizSet();

            final String palabra = s.get(0).substring(s.get(0).indexOf(".") + 1);
            tvTo.setText(s.get(0).substring(0, s.get(0).indexOf(".")));

            Collections.shuffle(s);
            for (String o : s)
            {
                transl.add(o.substring(o.indexOf(".") + 1));
            }           

            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood but...the reason why I put c incrementation in onclick is because I want to make the iteration be dependent on clicking the button. and the button is inside onCreate... I did the same (put loop iterating variable incrementation in an onclicklistener) in another activity and it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean? You want the whole do-while loop to execute when you click a List Item? Or you want one iteration to happen when you click?

Comment: I want the iteration of the loop to take place when the button is clicked - one iteration per one click...

Comment: Then you need to move the _contents of_ the do-while inside the `onItemClick()` method. Or put it in its own method and call it inside `onItemClick()`.

Comment: and where do I put the counter incrementation (c++) than? if I put it inside onItemClick - the whole loop goes round on one click; if I put it outside the onItemClick - I get an error; if I put it out of the OnItemClickListener - the program crashes.

Comment: if I put the contents of the loop insiede onItemClick() it won't neither.

Comment: If you just want to perform a code block once per click, up to a max, you do _not_ need a loop. You just need a counter to keep track of how many times you've clicked. I shuffled your code some to give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Just FYI, to make italics in comments, surround it with the underscore character: _

Comment: it works but there is another issue with which I will deal and post whether I managed to achieve what I want. _Thanks for help_